# Build PHP stdClass object simular to an Associative Array

Tags: php, object, stdclass

What other ways can you build a stdClass object similar to an associative array without using a loop, other than

```
$obj = (object)[ 'item1' => 1 , 'item2'=> 2 ];
```

Similar to how you can create an object in Javascript

```
var obj = { item1 : 1 , item : 2 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out the PHP [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) page...

Comment: `$obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->item1 = 1;
    $obj->item2 = 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Anthony on PHP Manual:

> In PHP 7 there are a few ways to create an empty object:

```
<?php
$obj1 = new \stdClass; // Instantiate stdClass object
$obj2 = new class{}; // Instantiate anonymous class
$obj3 = (object)[]; // Cast empty array to object

var_dump($obj1); // object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}
var_dump($obj2); // object(class@anonymous)#2 (0) {}
var_dump($obj3); // object(stdClass)#3 (0) {}
?>
```

For more on what he had to say visit the [PHP Manual documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#118679) with his answer.

To expand on his answer, the first one would look like this:

First example

```
$obj1 = new \stdClass;
$obj1->first = 1;

print_r($obj1);

// output
// stdClass Object
// (
//     [first] => 1
// )
```

Second example

```
$obj2 = new class{ };
$obj2->second = 2;

print_r($obj2);

// output
// class@anonymous Object
// (
//     [second] => 2
// )
```

Third example

```
$obj3 = (object)[];
$obj3->third = 3;

print_r($obj3);

// output
// stdClass Object
// (
//     [third] => 3
// )
```

You could do something along those lines; it's as easy as that